How to merge a release branch into main with many conflicting commits while keeping Git history clean?
I am dealing with a git repository that has a lot of conflicts between development and main. Git indicates there are 1000+ commits when merging the two, while in reality it should be around 40.
I am trying to merge my release branch (branched from development into main, but there are many conflicting commits. I resolved the conflicts by creating a new branch from main and merging that branch back into release with the -s ours strategy to bypass the conflicts. Normally we do a squash merge and delete the previous branch.
(For this temp branch I did not do this, since I suspect this is the reason why there are so many conflicts in the first place. I assume git cannot correctly find a common ancestor.)
However, there are now many "redundant?" commits in the history. Approximately 1000. Basically all commits since a very old release.
Our workflow is as follows:

Create a feature/* branch for a new feature
Merge in development if done (Always using --squash, no specific reason)
At some point create a release/* branch from development
Merge release/* into both main and development (Currently using --squash, reasons indicated above)

I cannot guarantee this has been done correctly in the past, but indicate this here since this might be part of the problem.
I want, and expected (perhaps naively):

No merge conflicts between release/* and main

What is the best way to proceed so that I can merge release into main without introducing a huge number of unnecessary commits and keeping the history clean and, more importantly, make sure we do actually solve this issue.

"and, more importantly, make sure we do actually solve this issue." The problematic part is "(Always using --squash, no specific reason)". The target branch never really incorporates the source commits, only a squashed result of the changes they bring. Thus the discrepancy. To avoid having to deal with all this again in the future, stop squashing.

I'm a bit confused how squashing feature branches can cause discrepancies. Do you care to elaborate? If that's the future fix, for sure we'll stop squashing feature branches.

Squash merges cause problems when you have multiple branches. The best case is if you have a feature branch and squash that and then delete the feature branch. I don’t feel that Squash is capable of dealing with anything more complex than that.

That's indeed how we are using it. We are also using it merge between release/* and main, but that can be seen as a delay of execution (not accepting 1000+ commit in history of main). I now have the following plan in mind:

Create the release branch from main (instead of development)
Cherry-pick the commits for this release on top of that
Force push this branch over development, at this point they should be identical
Merge to main when done (NOT SQUASHING)
Continue workflow as previously, but don't squash when merging to main.

